# How to eliminate mime type by using appcmd.exe

Tags: iis, encoding, http-compression

I added encoding mime type of static file for IIS by the following command such as the following. but I do not know how to eliminate the mime type.
Please let me know the appcmd command to eliminate mime-type that I added one.

sample : encoding static file

`appcmd set config /section:httpCompression /+staticTypes.[mimeType='text/xml',enabled='true'] /commit:apphost`

I tried to the following command.

`appcmd delete config /section:httpCompression /+staticTypes.[mimeType='text/xml',enabled='true'] /commit:apphost`

but it shows error.

Comment: Hi, is there any recent progress on this issue? Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add mime-type is like this:

```
appcmd set config /section:httpCompression /+staticTypes.[mimeType='text/xml',enabled='true'] /commit:apphost
```

Eliminate mime-type is like this: **(please note `/-` instead of `/+`)**

```
appcmd set config /section:httpCompression /-staticTypes.[mimeType='text/xml',enabled='true'] /commit:apphost
```

My test result was successful:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support!! I confirmed it.

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue, thank you!

Comment: I pushed check mark! Thanks for your support!!